# Finder crashing on 10.6.8 (Snow Leo)

Tags: finder, snow-leopard, crash

I am running 10.6.8 (Snow Leo) on a 2010 Mac Pro. 
The finder frequently crashes and restarts when I try to scroll through the finder view just looking at the list of files. 
I've gone to the user/library/preferences and deleted com.apple.finder.plist, but no improvement. The drive containing the OS isn't the issue, only another installed drive. A clean install of the OS hasn't helped, either. 
Any other ideas to fix this?

This is what console showed after crash -

```
12/9/14 3:52:42 PM  com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[162]  (com.apple.Finder[470]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault

12/9/14 3:52:50 PM  ReportCrash[600]    Saved crash report for Finder[470] version 10.6.8 (10.6.8) to /Users/macpro/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Finder_2014-12-09-155250_MacPro.crash
```

```

The report listed above, in the Log folder, is huge, over 3 full pages, if printed.

```
Process:         Finder [470]
Path:            /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/MacOS/Finder
Identifier:      com.apple.finder
Version:         10.6.8 (10.6.8)
Build Info:      Finder_FE-6650801~13
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [162]

Date/Time:       2014-12-09 15:52:35.773 -0500
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.8 (10K549)
Report Version:  6

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000201034220
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff87f4320b _class_getMethodNoSuper_nolock + 45
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff87f3ecef lookUpMethod + 127
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff87f36faa objc_msgSend + 198
3   com.apple.finder                0x0000000100063da5 0x100000000 + 408997
4   com.apple.finder                0x0000000100063a43 0x100000000 + 408131
5   com.apple.finder                0x0000000100063950 0x100000000 + 407888
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff843cbad5 _nsnote_callback + 167
7   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87e12fd0 __CFXNotificationPost + 1008
8   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87dff548 _CFXNotificationPostNotification + 200
9   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff843c2a36 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 101
10  com.apple.finder                0x000000010006371f 0x100000000 + 407327
11  com.apple.finder                0x000000010002fd3e 0x100000000 + 195902
12  com.apple.finder                0x0000000100030a5d 0x100000000 + 199261
13  com.apple.finder                0x0000000100030754 0x100000000 + 198484
14  com.apple.finder                0x000000010002f863 0x100000000 + 194659
15  com.apple.finder                0x000000010002f7d5 0x100000000 + 194517
16  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87e083d1 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 1361
17  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87e065c9 __CFRunLoopRun + 873
18  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87e05d8f CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 575
19  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff830f17ee RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 333
20  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff830f15f3 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 310
21  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff830f14ac BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 59
22  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff81c35eb2 _DPSNextEvent + 708
23  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff81c35801 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 155
24  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff81bfb68f -[NSApplication run] + 395
25  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff81bf43b0 NSApplicationMain + 364
26  com.apple.finder                0x0000000100005195 0x100000000 + 20885
27  com.apple.finder                0x0000000100005158 0x100000000 + 20824

Thread 1:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff83cd0c0a kevent + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff83cd2add _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 154
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff83cd27b4 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 185
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff83cd22de _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 252
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff83cd1c08 _pthread_wqthread + 353
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff83cd1aa5 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff83cb7d7a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff83cb83ed mach_msg + 59
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87e06902 __CFRunLoopRun + 1698
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87e05d8f CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 575
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87e05b16 CFRunLoopRun + 70
5   com.apple.DesktopServices       0x00007fff8998f326 TSystemNotificationTask::SystemNotificationTaskProc(void*) + 514
6   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x00007fff8026d0d1 PrivateMPEntryPoint + 63
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff83cf0fd6 _pthread_start + 331
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff83cf0e89 thread_start + 13

Thread 3:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff83cfb932 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87e28468 __CFSocketManager + 824
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff83cf0fd6 _pthread_start + 331
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff83cf0e89 thread_start + 13

Thread 4:  Dispatch queue: TFSVolumeInfo::GetSizingGCDQueue
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff83cc185e getuid + 10
1   com.apple.DesktopServices       0x00007fff899fdf66 TCFURLInfo::RealUserCanRead(bool*) const + 38
2   com.apple.DesktopServices       0x00007fff89a0d605 TOperationSizer::AccumulateSize(TCountedPtr<TCFURLInfo> const&, bool) + 403
3   com.apple.DesktopServices       0x00007fff89a0d9f4 TOperationSizer::Sizing(TCountedPtr<TCFURLInfo> const&) + 186
4   com.apple.DesktopServices       0x00007fff89a0db8e TOperationSizer::ComputeSize() + 206
5   com.apple.DesktopServices       0x00007fff899f10d8 TFSInfoSizer::Sizing(TCountedPtr<TFSInfo> const&) + 370
6   com.apple.DesktopServices       0x00007fff899a018b TNode::HandleFolderSizingRequest(TCountedPtr<TNodeTask> const&, TFolderSizingThread*) + 717
7   com.apple.DesktopServices       0x00007fff8999e807 TNode::HandleFolderSizingRequests(TNodeTask*, TFolderSizingThread*) + 205
8   com.apple.DesktopServices       0x00007fff8999e724 __PostFolderSizingTaskRequest_block_invoke_5 + 40
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff83cf3d64 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff83cd28d2 _dispatch_queue_drain + 251
11  libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff83cd2734 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 57
12  libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff83cd22de _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 252
13  libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff83cd1c08 _pthread_wqthread + 353
14  libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff83cd1aa5 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff83cd1a2a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff83cd1e3c _pthread_wqthread + 917
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff83cd1aa5 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000201034220  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x0000000102034200  rdx: 0x0000000000000001
  rdi: 0x0000000102034208  rsi: 0x00000001002757d2  rbp: 0x00007fff5fbfe140  rsp: 0x00007fff5fbfe140
   r8: 0x00000000ff000034   r9: 0x000000010156db88  r10: 0x000000012cc28a70  r11: 0x0000000000000000
  r12: 0x0000000000000001  r13: 0x00000001002757d2  r14: 0x00000001003dc578  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: 0x00007fff87f4320b  rfl: 0x0000000000010286  cr2: 0x0000000201034220
```

Comment: Open the Console program and make sure "All Messages" is selected in the left column. After Finder crashes see if there are any messages from Finder in the message window. If so, add them to your question. Also, look in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports and see if there are any crash reports from Finder. (To get to ~/Library, hold the Option key while selecting the Go menu from Finder.)

Comment: Have you tried repairing the disk and its permissions in Disk Utility? Also, 10.5.8 is Leopard. Snow Leopard is 10.6.x.

Comment: Post just the part of the crash log up to the line "Binary Images". Indent all the lines four spaces if you can so that it will be displayed as code. If you can't, don't worry about it, someone will edit it.

Comment: Title right, typo fixed in post. Snow for sure. For the non-OS disks, "permissions" is greyed out on Disk Utility. Does that make sense?

Comment: Done - loaded log data as requested. Thanks, again.

Comment: Sorry but there's nothing obvious to me. It looks like it's crashing in response to a notification and then is unable to find a class' method. But there's no telling what class that is. Some things to consider: Does it only happen in a certain folder with the installed drive? Can you list files from that drive with the `ls` command in Terminal? Can you connect the drive to another computer and see if it has the same problem?

Comment: I would try first Repair Disk on the volume that is causing the problem. If Finder is crashing perusing a disk volume, there's almost certainly something wrong with that volume's directory. Don't bother with Repair Permissions. That's just a waste of time even on the boot volume, and could not possibly affect a non-boot volume.